# How to install Gnome on Debian Squeeze in VirtualBox

Tags: debian, gnome, virtualbox

I'm doing a Cybrary course that uses [this VM from PentesterLab.com](https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/xss_and_mysql_file). I've downloaded the .ISO and launched it in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) v5.2.4. The VM boots up into Debian and works fine, but I can't seem to install a GUI.

I've tried Gnome, because that seems to be the most popular one, but none of the following commands work:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm3
sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment
```

Trying them with the `-f` and `-m` switches doesn't help. All of them say "Unable to locate package" except for `gdm3`, which actually tries to install but lists a bunch of dependencies and says "but it is not installable" for each one.

When I do `sudo apt-get update` it runs but with some "Failed to fetch" errors.

The VM is bridged and has network connectivity; it has its own IP address on my network and can ping and be pinged from other computers, as well as ping Internet sites. The VM has base memory of 1024MB and an 8GB virtual hard drive. It's running 32-bit Debian 2.6.32-5-686.

I'm not sure if the problem is related to Linux, the VM environment, or me not knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: [Don't post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They're unsearchable, hard to read, and most importantly here, one screenful does not contain all the information. Copy-paste the **complete** output from the commands. If you can't copy-paste from inside the VM, save it to a file and copy or upload that file.

Comment: [A distribution designed for pentesting is not a good introduction for Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). This isn't Kali, it's a different customization of Debian, it might as well be. Usually, you need to know the basics of Linux before you can start with the basics of pentesting. Start with a normal distribution like Ubuntu, Mint, elementary, ...

Comment: @Gilles I'm trying to figure out how to export the text. I can save it to a file but can't seem to bring that file from the VM to my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian Squeeze went End Of Life in 2016 as can be seen [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze).

You'll need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point your VM at the Debian archive repository:

Use:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main
```

In addition, add `Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Comment: I edited `sources.list` and ran `sudo apt-get update` which seemed to work. But trying to install gnome or gdm3 fails, saying "Unable to locate package."

Comment: How would I find out the correct package name? Looking through `tasksel` doesn't seem to show any desktop environments (or at least, none with names I would recognize).

Comment: I've looked through all the packages in the `tasksel` list (locally created, obsolete, and virtual) and there's no option for "Graphical Desktop Environment", a GUI, Gnome, or anything that seems related. Would it be called something else?

Comment: I've just downloaded and ran the ISO you link to in your question and after applying the changes I state in my answer I get both the `gnome-desktop-environment` package and a `Graphical Desktop Environment` option in `tasksel`.  Check everything again :-)

Comment: Hmm... okay, thanks for checking it. I'll reboot the VM and give it another shot.

Comment: @garethTheRed That did the trick... thanks! VM is out of disk space so I'll reboot and adjust the space, but the Gnome package download worked. Appreciate the help!